# Python urllib.encode @ symbol?

Tags: python

The Python documentation for httplib (http://docs.python.org/2/library/httplib.html) shows the 
urllib.urlencode parameter keys preceded with an `@` symbol. I don't see this in other examples. What is the @ symbol doing in this case?

```
>>> import httplib, urllib
>>> params = urllib.urlencode({'@number': 12524, '@type': 'issue'})
>>> headers = {"Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
...            "Accept": "text/plain"}
>>> conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("bugs.python.org")
>>> conn.request("POST", "", params, headers)
```

Comment: Because the bug trackers expects `@number` etc... as parameters and they need to be escaped...? It doesn't have any special meaning if that's what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as you can see, it has no meaning:

```
>>> import httplib, urllib
>>> params = urllib.urlencode({'@number': 12524, '@type': 'issue', '@action': 'show'})
>>> print params
'%40action=show&%40number=12524&%40type=issue'
>>> params = urllib.urlencode({'number': 12524, 'type': 'issue', 'action': 'show'})
>>> print params
'action=show&type=issue&number=12524'
```

it just formats the special character `@` into `%40` that is being used by http://bugs.python.org as `POST` keys, and the reason why they use it is internal to that site's engine...